# Swapping an image for text at lower resolutions

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, media-queries

I have a large image that gets cut off slightly on the right on lower resolutions. At lower resolutions I wouldn't mind just swapping the image out for text (its a countdown I can just specify the date) how do you do this? I have managed to get rid of the image at the lower resolution using display:none;

### HTML

```
<div id ="image"><div/>
```

Ideally I would have something akin to:

```
<p>a date here....</p>  <---this value hidden until the resolution hits the lower margins
```

### CSS

```
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    image:display.none;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put both the image and the paragraph elements within your HTML. Change your CSS for this:

```css
@media ( max-width:500px ) {
    #image img { display:none; }
    #image p { display:block; } 
}

/* Example when the viewport is bigger */
@media ( min-width:500px ) {
    #image img { display:inline; }
    #image p { display:none; }
}
```

Comment: Careful with this... `img` are `inline` by default

Answer (score 2):

### HTML

```
<div id="image">
    <img src='...'>
    <p>a date here...</p>
</div>
```

### CSS

```css
@media (max-width: 500px) {
    #image > img {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 500px) {
    #image > p {
        display: none;
    }
}
```